# How do I create an alter table statement with MyBatis? MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have the following

```
@Mapper
public interface StatMapper {
    @Update("alter table stats reorganize partition #{pFirst},#{pSecond} into ( "
            + "partition #{pSecond} values less than (#{dSecond}) "
            + ");")
    public void updateFirstPartition(@Param("pFirst")String pFirst, @Param("pSecond")String pSecond, @Param("dSecond")LocalDate dSecond);
```

It gives the following error

> 2019-09-30 21:58:23.067 DEBUG 13728 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.m.StatMapper.updateFirstPartition  : ==>  Preparing: alter table stats reorganize partition ?,? into ( partition ? values less than (?) );
>   
>     2019-09-30 21:58:23.093 DEBUG 13728 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.m.StatMapper.updateFirstPartition  : ==> Parameters: p20180901(String), p20181001(String), p20181001(String), 2018-10-01(Date)
>   
>     Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>       ### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''p20180901','p20181001' into ( partition 'p20181001' values less than ('2018-10-' at line 1

How can I issue this `alter table` statement using MyBatis?

The statement should look like this (`p0` and `p1` substituted by `p20180901` and `p20181001`):

```
alter table stats reorganize partition p0,p1 into (
    partition p1 values less than ('2018-10-01')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${}` is a text substitution and `#{}` is a placeholder in a `java.sql.PreparedStatement` (see the [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the details).
So, with your code, MyBatis generates a prepared statement as follows...

```java
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
  "alter table stats reorganize partition ?,? into (partition ? values less than (?))");
```

...and it fails because you cannot use a placeholder for a partition name.

The following should work.

```java
@Update("alter table stats reorganize partition ${pFirst},${pSecond} into ( "
  + "partition ${pSecond} values less than (#{dSecond}) "
  + ")")
```

Comment: Wow both of us 'just now', same second even.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `${pFirst},${pSecond}` instead of `#{pFirst},#{pSecond}`.